# Change brightness of screen when receiving UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Today I'm developing an alarm clock application. I have to use UILocalNotification. The Alarm Clock will set the date time then when it comes, some notification fires with sound and message. I want at this time the brightness of the screen (may be home screen or lock screen) increases to the maximum level (the alarm clock application is in background this time). Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Apple doesn't allow your app to modify the state of the device when its not in the foreground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think people are reading your question properly. 
You can only adjust the brightness of the screen when your app is front & centre. You cannot change the screen brightness on any other screen (without using private APIs), such as the home screen or lock screen, from your app.

Just for clarification, on iOS5 and above you can change the brightness **when your app is displayed** using

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

However as soon as you hit the home button, or your app closes, the screen will revert to the users current brightness preferences.

Comment: Yes, you really understand my question, I want change the brightness of other screens when my app in the background, it's one of my requirements. So I should refuse this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for changing brightness :

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

But I think it only works for iOS 5+.

Comment: These lines of code not applicable when my app is in the background.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow your app to modify the state of the device when its not in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do that by adding a blackView on your view and change its alpha value, it will looks like you are changing the brightness.

```
     UIView *  polygonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 500, 500)];
     polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     polygonView.alpha = 0.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this initially set screen brightness less

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.5];
```

then when notification comes then make it full

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

Comment: These lines of code not applicable when my app in the background.